# JQ - merge two fields to an array with another field name

Tags: json, parsing, jq

I'm trying to change a data structure, but I'm not able to find a clue how to do this with jq. I'm curious to learn.

Input:

```
[ 
  { "capital": "St. John's",
    "lat": 17.1172,
    "lon": -61.8457
  },
  { "capital": "Buenos Aires",
    "lat": -34.6051,
    "lon": -58.4004
  },
]
```

Desired output:

```
[ 
  { "capital": "St. John's",
    "lonlat": [ -61.8457, 17.1172]
  },
  { "capital": "Buenos Aires",
    "lonlat": [-58.4004, -34.6051]
  },
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Form the JSON with the fields clubbed into an array and remove the fields thereafter

```
map(. + { lonlat : [.lon, .lat] } | del(.lat, .lon))
```

[jqplay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/-KoFfbNap-)